# Axios posting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I'm building a mock facebook app using MERN Stack. When I try to save posts to my database, it keeps throwing two errors. One is in the back end and says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` and the other is in the front end and says `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 500`

This is my front end API.js page

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  // Gets all posts
  getPosts: function() {
    return axios.get("/api/users/posts");
  },
  // Gets the post with the given id
  getPost: function(id) {
    return axios.get("/api/users/posts/" + id);
  },
  // Deletes the post with the given id
  deletePost: function(id) {
    return axios.delete("/api/users/posts/" + id);
  },
  // Saves a post to the database
  savePost: function(postData) {
    return axios.post("/api/users/posts", postData);
  }
};
```

This is my handleSubmit function

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        // Preventing the default behavior of the form submit (which is to refresh the page)
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Saving post to database
        API.savePost(this.state)
        .then(data => {
          console.log("data: ", data);
          this.setState({
            title: data.data.title,
            body: data.data.body,
            
          });

        });
      };
```

This is my back end postController.js, where `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` is being thrown.

```
const db = require("../models");
console.log("--------------------------------------");
console.log("Controller Reached");
console.log("--------------------------------------");
// Defining methods for the postController
module.exports = {
  findAll: function(req, res) {
    console.log("----------------------findAll------------------------  ");
    console.log("req.query: ", req.query);
    db.User.posts
      .find(req.query)
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  findById: function(req, res) {
    db.User.posts
      .findById(req.params.id)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  create: function(req, res) {
    console.log("create func");
    console.log("req.body: ", req.body);
    db.User.posts
      .create(req.body) //error here
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  update: function(req, res) {
    db.User.posts
      .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  remove: function(req, res) {
    db.User.posts
      .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
      .then(dbModel => dbModel.remove())
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
};
```

And these are my backend API routes for the posts (I removed other routes that weren't related to the issue)

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const db = require("../../models");
const passport = require("passport");
const postController = require("../../controllers/postController");

router
  .route("/posts")
  .post(postController.create)
  .get(postController.findAll)
  .put(postController.update)
  .delete(postController.remove);
console.log("/posts reached");

// Matches with "/api/books/:id"
router
  .route("/posts/:id")
  .get(postController.findById)
  .put(postController.update)
  .delete(postController.remove);

//router get for login >>> router.get("/")
//router post for logout
//router.get for profile page

module.exports = router;
```

edit: This is my user model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const passport = require("passport");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    following: [{
        User: String,
        id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
    }],
    followers: [{
        User: String,
        id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
    }],
    posts: [{
        title: String,
        body: String,
        postedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        dateCreated: Date,
        comments: [{body:"string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
    }],
    dateCreated: Date,
    savedFiles:[{}],
    favoritePosts: [],
    avatarImage: [{Image: String}],
    jumboImg: [{Image: String}],
    profile: {
        job: String,
        location: String,
        school: String,
        bio: String,
        interests: []
    }
});

var User = (module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema));
module.exports.createUser = function (newUser, callback) {
  console.log("createUser - newUser", newUser)
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
};
module.exports.getUserByEmail = function (email, callback) {
  console.log("getUserByEmail", email)
  var query = { email: email };
  console.log(query);
  User.findOne(query, callback);
};
module.exports.getUserById = function (id, callback) {
  console.log("getUserById", id);
  User.findById(id, callback);
};
module.exports.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  console.log("comparePassword")
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, function (
    email,
    password,
    done
  ) {
    console.log("LocalStrategy");
    User.getUserByEmail(email, function (err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Unknown User" });
      }
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password" });
        }
      });
    });
  })
);
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  console.log("serializeUser", user.id)
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  console.log("deserializeUser", id);
  User.getUserById(id, function (err, user) {
    console.log("deserializeUser - user", `name="${user.name}" \nemail="${user.email}"\npassword=${user.password} `);
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems `db.User.posts` has the problem which is defined in "models". Can you post your "models" or some other file that defines your User object?

Comment: @senta I added the user model in the post. Thank you for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.posts` is `undefined` because `.posts` is a property of instance of `User`. Thus you need to instantiate the user first. In this case, by finding an existing object from User collection.

Since you defined `User.posts` as primitive arrays, not reference to another collection, the code will be something like below.

```js
create: function (req, res) {
  // 1. find the existing user (I guess passport does the job)
  db.User.findById(req.body.userid).then((user) => {
    // 2. add an post
    user.posts.push({
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
      postedBy: req.body.userid,
      dateCreated: Date.now(),
      comments: [],
    });

    // 3. persist the changes
    user.save();
  });
}
```

If you want to separate the collection, which I believe better, you need to create a new object on the separated collection with the reference to the user posted.

```js
// Post schema
var postSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  postedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  dateCreated: Date,
  comments: [{ body: "string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }],
});

// The controller
create: function(req, res) {
  // 1. find the existing user (or you get id from Passport session)
  db.User.findById(req.body.userid).then((user) => {
    // 2. add an post set "postedBy" as the user
    return Post.create({
      postedBy: user._id,
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
      dateCreated: Date.now(),
    });
  });
}
```

Here is the official documentation about referencing: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your answer was super helpful, but I've learned that my req.body.userid is turning up null. Would you by any chance know how to fix that?

Comment: I used `req.body.userid` just for example. You should be able to get it from the Passport session if the request is authenticated.